# Rotation mode not saved with Collada Export

Tags: export, collada

I'm trying to export simple animation file to collada(.dae), But I think rotation mode does not saved as I did. [image: in blender]

Referring to  [Exporting from Blender even better collada, breaks animations](https://godotengine.org/qa/39576/exporting-from-blender-even-better-collada-breaks-animations)

as you can  see, I changed rotation mode to Quaternion in blender, but collada files' rotation mode is still Euler in second picture.
Am I missing something?

Uploaded .blend and exported .dae file on here:
[Quaternion Test](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16loFK_HNDI6SYBaQHRKDKmwbxf_I2hPR/view?usp=sharing)
Thanks for any help.